# API design: how to handle third party's APIs errors

Tags: rest, api, error-handling

I'm building an API for our client. Let's call it MY_API.

1) Our client POST /user with json request {username: 'TEST', password: 'xxx'}.

2) MY_API will register the user 'TEST' on a third-party api such as https://register.xxx.xxx. Let's call it THEIR_API

3) If THEIR_API returns 200 with payload {username: 'TEST' token: 'xxx'} , MY_API will extract these information and send to the client.

4) If THEIR_API returns 400, MY_API will just forward the payload to the client.

Here is my question:
on step 4), should I extract the error message and then send to the client? or forward is fine for an API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, don't relay on THEIR_API error message, you never know today everything looks fine but tomorrow what they are gonna expose as error. 
For example they may expose some DB information which is not a good practice or they may send some unreadable message. So better to take control on your side.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll try to send my own error messages rather than forwarding.